# How can I export from unity to blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, textures, blender

I have an object in my unity editor scene it's with colors and textures and materials. But when I drag the asset prefab to the blender it's gray without the textures colors materials.

This is a screenshot from the unity editor : On the left is the big space ship with colors and textures materials :

[image: Object in unity]

This is the prefab asset settings :

[image: Prefab asset settings]

And when I drag the prefab asset to blender the result is the 3d object but fray without the colors,textures,materials :

[image: In blender]

Is there any way to export or take object from unity to blender with all the colors,textures,materials?

Comment: of what file type is your "prefab" asset? And how exactly are you opening it in blender? You probably woukd just need to reassign the according image files to the materials in blender (albedo, normal-map, reflection-map etc). Also you might be not in textured preview mode in blender .. do the images appear when you render the scene (F12 .. might have to add lights and position the camera)?

Comment: Seems like you did cross posting for this question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193812/how-can-i-export-from-unity-to-blender
I think you already got an answer there that your question is a duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures